# Convert large integer to float

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an integer into a float like this (simplified):

```
int64_t x = -((int64_t)1 << 63);
float y = x;
```

With MSVC 2013 on a 64-bit Windows 7 this works just fine, but with gcc 4.8 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit I get a positive value for x. I disabled all optimizations and looked at the variables in gdb. I even tried evaluating with gdb directly in order to find the cause of the problem:

```
(gdb) print (float)(-((int64_t)1 << 63))
$33 = 9,22337204e+18

(gdb) print (float)(-9223372036854775808)
$39 = 9,22337204e+18
```

As can be seen, not even adding explicit casts solves the problem. I am a bit confused since `float` should be able to hold much larger numbers (in terms of absolute value). `sizeof(float) == 4` and `sizeof(size_t) == 8` in case it matters. It seems that the value -2^63 is some magic limit, since -2^63+1 is converted perfectly fine:

```
(gdb) print (float)(-((int64_t)1 << 63) + 1)
$44 = -9,22337149e+18
```

What is the reason that the sign is lost in the conversion for values <=-2^63? The value -2^63 can be represented by int64_t as well as float; and it works on other platforms as described above.

Comment: `(int64_t)1 << 63` is shifting a `1` into the sign bit, therefore is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. It now works with `(gdb) print (float)(-(int64_t)((uint64_t)1 << 63)) $48 = -9,22337204e+18`

Comment: Remember that `float` only has a 24-bit mantissa!

Comment: Just use `INT64_MIN` and avoid any bit shift issues.

Comment: If possible, do the cast to float before the negation. Both 2^63 and -(2^63) can be represented in float.

Comment: Hm... That works in gdb, but not in the C code. Is there any way to convert `-(1 << x)` to a float, where x=63 at run time?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Converting to float earlier was the key, thank you. IT now works with `(-(float)((uint64_t)1 << 63))`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

The instruction `(int64_t)1 << 63` is shifting a `1` into the sign bit, therefore is Undefined Behaviour.

Even if the shifting was successful and gave `0x8000000000000000` that is the minimum (and negative) value that can be supported, so then negating the value with

```
-((int64_t)1 << 63)
```

puts the value out of range of a positive signed 64 bit `int`.

Comment: ... which again is undefined behaviour. So each compiler is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid undefined behavior, multiply by powers of two using [the `ldexp` standard function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ldexp/): `- ldexp(1.0, 63)`.